# Which is more efficient JavaScript array search or MySQL LIKE query?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, arrays

I know this is a somewhat nebulous question but which algorithm would be more efficient and/or "faster"?

Searching through a preloaded JavaScript array of names or using the MySQL query `"SELECT NAME WHERE NAME LIKE '%VARIABLE%'`? The MySQL would be called using jquery AJAX to access a PHP file.

A little background on my website, it is a site primarily for mobile users and uses a mix of jquery and php to deliver content. In this case the user would be searching for a specific name within a list of **~22,000** unique names.

I have also thought about storing the table using LocalStorage as a cache, but then that requires an additional (though maybe less costly?) step of verifying/updating/loading the cache.

If more information is needed please let me know and thanks in advance.

EDIT:

A bit of extra information, the user can and probably will be searching for multiple non-unique values. For example: a search value of 'Jane' can and should return the results `'Jane Smith', 'Janet Smith', 'Jane Doe', 'Janess Whatver', 'jfhfuhd_JANE_dfifhf, 'Blah'`(don't know who would ever have a name like that but if it was in the database and they searched Jane it should be return along with the others)

Comment: how many times will the user use this functionality in an average session? how frequently? I'm voting for mysql.

Comment: MySQL with indexing on the names

Comment: Just a question: What's faster? Dumping 22k of data from the DB into an array AND have JS go over them? Or a trip to the DB looking for a single value?

Comment: I would definitely use MySQL in this case - especially with mobile users, you can't always guarantee the speed of their device, whereas with MySQL you've got full visibility and can choose to optimize where necessary.

Comment: Ah, something I forgot to mention, the user isn't necessarily searching for one specific value, i.e. searching for Jane can and should return 'Jane Smith', 'Jane Doe', 'Janet Smith', 'Janess Doe', etc

Comment: In the time you are loading the array, MySQL probably already found the value. Besides do you really want to push an entire table to **every** client that want to search for a name? even if it is faster, I wouldn't do it.

Comment: @Jospeh the Dreamer good point. I presume the data would only be dumped once before the array is searched using JavaScript. This would take place on the client-side so would be dependent on client hardware

Comment: Another way to put forward this question, "Which one is faster and better on a mobile website, (1) executing an SQL query, yielding ~22,000 results, on each page visit and embed ~22,000 names in response _every time_ a page is visited OR (2) make an ajax call to run an SQL query, yielding ~20 results, only when user wants to?" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just speculation, but without testing, immediately I'd go for the MySQL query. MySQL has been optimised by its developers for the best search/sort algorithms - that's its job (one look at their [benchmark manual](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/benchmarks/) will give you an idea as to just how much they care). The people who write the JavaScript interpreters won't have had as much time to devote to optimising their search/sort algorithms.

As an added plus, the Javascript option is dependent on the client's computer speed and browser - a slow device with a poorly implemented interpreted will take a much longer time. However, the MySQL option depends on *your* server, and therefore is completely under your control.

**Some tests**

JavaScript array with 10,000 values, comparing against a set value (jsfiddle.net/c6rpK/) - I get approximately 12ms

For the same test using MySQL I get 2.3ms

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with MySQL. In fact, I wouldn't even think of trying to compare the two.

Databases are good at handling data: it's their job. Let them do it.

Storing the data locally has quite some disadvantages:

- What if a piece of data changes? Will you re-post all data to all clients again?
- You have to send all data to all clients to begin with.
- Will the client have room (reserved) for that data?

The best of all of course is to index the names, either completely or partially.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with indexing, I'm planning on googling but could you give me a general idea of what are they/how they work?

Comment: Indexing is the process, where a certain part of a record is placed in an index. Compare it to an index at the back of a book. Using that, you can get to a piece of information very fast, without having to browse through all the pages. Of course [wikipedia has all the info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index).

Comment: From the MySQL page on indexes:

The following SELECT statements do not use indexes:

SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE '%Patrick%';
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE other_col;

In the first statement, the LIKE value begins with a wildcard character. In the second statement, the LIKE value is not a constant.


My query string looks exactly the first query so an index would not be helpful it seems?

Comment: You could index in different ways. For example, you could create a table with words that are indexed and refer to the fullname table.